# How to initialize a rowtype array in pl/pgsql?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I need to declare an array of records that will be inserted into some table then. But i cannot find a way to initialize this array. Like, for table like this:

```
create table mytable
(
  id serial,
  value varchar
);
```

I need something like:

```
do
$$
    declare 
        rowsForTable mytable%rowtype[] := array [
           ( id=1, value='val 1' ),
           ( id=2, value='val 2' ),
           ( id=3 )
    ];
```

How could I achieve it?
Thank you!

Comment: Any reason why you use an array instead of standard `INSERT … VALUES …`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use just `mytable[]` for `rowsForTable` datatype, not `mytable%rowtype[]`. Use positional row literals w/o names to initialize the array.

```sql
-- setup
create table mytable
(
  id serial,
  value text
);

-- demo
do 
$$
declare 
 rowsForTable mytable[] := array[(1, 'val 1'), (2, 'val 2'), (3, null)];
begin
  insert into mytable select * from unnest (rowsForTable);
end;
$$;
```

Please note the `null` in the third array element.

Comment: Thank you, will test it as well. A quick question - is omitting %rowtype crucial? From my experience with oracle, i'd prefer to use it as i suppose it's more compatible. And the same question: is there a way to specify field/column name and/or type?

Comment: @BbIKTOP - `%rowtype` is optional in postgres. Against Oracle, any table in Postgres makes composite type with same name at creation time. The syntax of SQL and PL/pgSQL is similar to Oracle, but implementation is different, sometimes very different (PL/pgSQL is internally absolutely different than PL/SQL)

Comment: @PavelStehuleyep, I already noticed that but i'd like to keep it as much compatible as possible. i tested it and found that with %rowtype it simply does not work. just curious, what is the reason for that?

Comment: @BbIKTOP - The syntax `xx%rowtype[]` is not supported, I think. Probably, there is not strong reason for this. I think so this is oversight in implementation. 20 years ago there was a idea of stronger compatibility with PL/SQL, and PL/pgSQL got some PL/SQL's syntaxes. But this idea was leaved as impossible and nobody try to fix not too important issues related to this. I don't think so using %rowtype keyword has any benefit in pg.

Comment: @PavelStehule well, i need it just to transfer data once, so my question was more like theoretical. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Using the `array` and `ROW` constructors in PostgreSQL, you can initialise an array of composite types (records) for insertion into a table. While you cannot initialise fields directly, as in your example, you can initialise each field separately using the `ROW` constructor. This is how:

```
DO $$ 
DECLARE
    rowsForTable mytable%rowtype[];
BEGIN
    rowsForTable := array[
        ROW(1, 'val 1'::varchar),
        ROW(2, 'val 2'::varchar),
        ROW(3, NULL::varchar)
    ];

    -- Loop through the array and insert values into the table
    FOREACH row IN ARRAY rowsForTable
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO mytable (id, value) VALUES (row.id, row.value);
    END LOOP;
END $$;
```

This method utilises a loop to put values into the table after initialising each field using the `ROW` constructor. Due to the loop, it's crucial to keep in mind that this approach works best for smaller datasets. For larger inserts, a more effective strategy like a single `INSERT INTO` line with a `VALUES` clause could be preferable.

Comment: Thank you. Will test it right now. Can't find yet, is there a way to specify columns/fields names and types in the ROW constructor?

Sorry, missed that type is specified. But what about name?

Comment: @BbIKTOP - no, there is not that way.

Comment: does not work: "[42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "[" Position: 55" Probably I did something wrong, please help

Comment: Well, found that after removing %rowtype it is working. Could you please correct your answer?